# How to get a certain mongodb document value from each document as a list of strings?

Tags: c#, mongodb

In every MongoDB document in my collection I have a "project_name" field that is a String. I want to retrieve a `List<String>` object for each of those distinct values (hence group in the example below), but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have looked into projections and everything but cannot find an example that works for me.

This is the closest I have gotten:

```
public List<String> GetProjectNames1()
{
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(VehiclesCollection);

    var aggregation = collection.Aggregate()
        .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$project_name" } })
        .ToList()
        .Select(i => i.GetValue("_id").ToString())
        .ToList();

    return aggregation;
}
```

I feel like there is a much better way though, using projections in some way.

Comment: By closest, do you mean your code above works?

Comment: What version of the driver are you using? The newest version is all async unless you're using the legacy APIs.

Comment: @metame Yes, it works, but I don't feel like it's the right way to do it.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Will verify when I'm back in the office in the morning, but I feel like it's 2.0? I don't really want to do async if I can help it, but if that's the only way to go then I will.

Comment: If all you want is "distinct values for a field" and also as an array, then why not use the `.distinct()` method as is appropriate in the driver? That is exactly what it does, and without the additional juggling to tranform a BSON document to just the values of a specific key.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Doesn't that just give distinct BSON documents though? I'm not sure how to use that to get a distinct List<String>.

Comment: Nope. The `.distinct()` method just returns the distinct "values" of the field from which was specified. Not a document, but just a `List<String>`, or appropriate type.

Comment: @BlakesSeven So in the case above where does the Distinct go? After group? Will test it when I'm back in the office.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I can't use .distinct() on an aggregate query. Any idea how I can change this?

Comment: I thought your only objective here is a list of distinct keys only. The [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method is it's own method and seperate from `.aggregate()` just as that is separate from `.find()`. All API's support this method.